# Flex child with no-wrap child overflowing off screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a very specific flex use case that I don't quite understand why it's behaving how it is. I have two columns. The right column has a fixed width, and `flex-shrink: 0`. The left column has `flex-shrink: 1`, `flex-grow: 1`, and, crucially, a child with `width: 100%`, `white-space: nowrap`, and `overflow-x: scroll`.

What I would expect is for the left column to fill the remaining width and then the overflow to scroll. However, what actually happens is the left column pushes the right column off screen.

You can see an example here: https://codepen.io/benlorantfy/pen/oNXKXOe

I'm looking for an explanation of why it's behaving this way and what I could do to fix it.

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-child-1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.nowrap-el {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-color: grey;
}

.flex-child-2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child-1">
    <div class="nowrap-el">
      This should fill remaining space instead of pushing flex-child-2 off the screen. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas in augue volutpat, sagittis ante et, tincidunt mauris. Morbi vitae convallis erat, eget vulputate lacus.
      Nunc a justo aliquet, facilisis justo eget, semper velit. Nunc quis elementum tortor. Nam vestibulum aliquet nunc, id
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child-2">This should not be shoved off screen</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, I looked at your code pen and removed the white-space: nowrap and it filled the width of the screen without pushing anything off it. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I'd like to keep the white-space nowrap. It should fill the width of the screen but then scroll if there's more content.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding `overflow-x: hidden` on `flex-child-1`. (I also added `flex-basis: 0` for good measure but I don't think it does anything). This seems to tell the browser to respect the widths and overflows set on children. I'm not sure why this works or where in the spec it says this, but if anyone knows and wants to comment, feel free.

```
.flex-child-1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

See live demo on: https://codepen.io/benlorantfy/pen/ExjqJBM